# One specific field of my -angularjs- form must be editable only if at least one other field of this same form was modified

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope

I added the possibility to modify an existent document in my application. 
They're several fields on my form, all of them are already filled with the values that can be modified.
What i'm trying to do is adding on my form the possibility to edit the field X only if at least one of the other field of the form have been modified.

To do so, i tried to setPristine on init. But it doesn't seem to work.

`$scope.invoiceRequestForm.$setPristine()` is undefined.

I'm open to alternative way to resolve this issue.

Here's my code :

The Template :

```
<form ng-init="setPristine()" class="form-horizontal mode-edit" name="invoiceForm" ng-class="{'panelsheet-content': $state.current.data.mode !== 'search'}" novalidate>
<input type="text" name="legacyVATRate" ng-model="vm.vatRateIsReviewed">
<input type="text" name="refClient" ng-model="vm.invoiceRequest.client.refClient" ng-disabled="invoiceForm.$pristine">
</form>
```

The Controller :

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('dk').controller('InvoiceEditCtrl', InvoiceEditCtrl);

  /* @ngInject */
  function InvoiceEditCtrl(
    $window,
    $sessionStorage,
    CRUDAlerts,
    $scope,
    InvoiceResolved,
    ClientResolved,
    Client,
    $state,
    $stateParams,
    InvoiceService,
    VATService,
    $translate,
    RegExpList,
    CommonService
  ) {
    // private vars

    var vm = this;

    function setPristine() { return $scope.invoiceForm.$setPristine();
}
})();
```

I'm using AngularJS 1.4.0

Comment: Is this some different form? `name="invoiceForm"` but you're looking at `invoiceRequestForm.$pristine` and you should propably use [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) and your input is hidden, can you elaborate what changes its value when it's enabled?

Comment: Hey @barbsan , yes indeed, it was a typo, i simplified my form to extract my concern and did some mistake doing that :)